# Crystal reports, formatting of reports manually

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I am using Visual Studio, .NET to create a web application that uses Crystal reports, is there any way that i can format these reports in an organized manner other than doing it manually drag and drop?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, reports are XML files (in SQL reporting services, i'm not sure for crystal reports) , so you can generate them :)

Comment: i am generating them, but when they come in the report page its pretty disorganized with lines all over the place, i want to format them to be more organized, any ideas?

Comment: The way i did it using Reporting Services is generate the report using the tool as i would like and then try to generate the same xml. The xml is a bit dirty but it's running. Try to generate some simple reports in order to test this method but it works well. (I had use it in order to print stuffs !)